# Using Sqlite3 to insert data into database using a loop

Tags: mysql, for-loop, sqlite

I'm just getting started with databases and could use help inserting information into a database using a loop.

I made a simple database table with three headings: ISBN, Author, Price.

I would like to use lists containing the ISBNs, Authors, and Prices and insert each ISBN, Author, and Price to the database table using one for loop.

Here is my code:

```
ISBN1=ISBNs[0]
Author1=Authors[0]
Price1=Prices[0]


db=sqlite3.connect('My_Book_Inventory.sqlite')
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''Insert INTO ISBNS(ISBN,Author,Price) VALUES(?,?,?)''',(ISBN1,Author1,Price1))
db.commit()
```

Could someone help me get from inserting each ISBN manually by calling the values in the lists ISBN1, ISBN2, ISBN3 etc. into actually doing this all with a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have `n` records that you want to insert them. Assuming `ISBNs`, `Authors` and `Prices` are arrays of size `n`, you can do this:

```
for i in range(0, n):
    ISBN = ISBNs[i]
    Author = Authors[i]
    Price = Prices[i]

    db=sqlite3.connect('My_Book_Inventory.sqlite')
    cursor=db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''Insert INTO ISBNS(ISBN,Author,Price) VALUES(?,?,?)''',(ISBN,Author,Price))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried your solution but for some reason I got an error:     for (int i=0; i < n; ++i)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: ok, I deduced you are using python. The answer is updated, use the new code

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly, I just had to change your first line to: for i in range(0, len(ISBNs)):